# Getting error while connecting kerberos secured phoenix from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I am getting following error while connecting to kerberos secured phoenix environment through spark java code.

ASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'. javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
 Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147"

My spark code is as follows:-

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[4]")
                .setAppName("phoenix-test")
                .set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
                .set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos")
                .set("hadoop.rpc.protection", "privacy")
                .set("spark.yarn.principal", "infinityadm/lswpbacrapn3d.nam.nsroot.net@NAMUXDEV.DYN.NSROOT.NET")
                .set("spark.yarn.keytab", "C://files//infinityadm_lswpbacrapn3d.nam.nsroot.net@NAMUXDEV.DYN.NSROOT.NET.keytab")

sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);

        JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf));
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);
        DataFrame fromPhx = sqlContext
                .read()
                .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
                .option("table", "ODS.TRF_DEF_PRM")
                .option("zkURL", "url:/hbase-dev")
                /*.option("zkURL","lswpbacrapn1d,lswpbacrapn2d,lswpbacrapn3d:2181:/hbase-dev")*/
                .load();
```

My vm options in intellij are as follows:-

```
-DCPB_LOG_PATH=C:/Users/PB42185/Logs
-DSERVICE_NAME=infinity-utils
-DJava.security.krb5.conf=C:/Users/2185/krb5.conf
-DJava.security.krb5.ini=C:/Users/2185/krb5.ini
-DJava.security.krb5.realm=@APACUXUAT.DYN.NSROOT.NET
-Dzookeeper.sasl.client=false
-Dzookeeper.sasl.client.username=adm
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

Comment: hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Comment: Okay,from next time i will not include such phrases